# Recursion with 1D array

Tags: java, recursion

Ive been staring at this problem for hours. For some reason I understand flood fill and recursion with 2-D arrays, but can't seem to even get started on this problem:

You have three assistants working for you. One is named Jeff, the other is named Jeff, and the third is named Jeff. They all type with the same speed of one page per minute. You came to your office today with a bunch of papers you need to have typed as soon as possible. You have to distribute the papers among your assistants in such a way that they finish all the papers at the earliest possible time. "Jeff do this," you yell. "Jeff do that," you say. "Jeff, finish the job," you admonish. So Jeff does. But you need to help him. So you have this APT.

Your task is, given a int[] with the number of pages for each paper, return the minimum number of minutes needed for your assistants to type all these papers. Assume that they can't divide a paper into parts, that is, each paper is typed by one person. For example, given {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, the function should return 10 because 7+3=10, 6+2+1=9, and 5+4=9 (there are also other combinations of these numbers that would yield the same result).

Comment: I'm not sure that recursion would be the most desirable thing to use here.

Comment: How would you do it then. A friend said recursion is the way to go.

Comment: This is a NP-complete problem. Do you need optimal results, or are approximations ok?

Comment: Approximations are ok